# Comparing two lists of nested lists and returning the added/changed/removed items

Tags: c#, list, nested, comparison

I've looked at many similar questions on stackoverflow, but I haven't seen an exact match for my problem.

I need to compare two "lists of nested lists" and capture the differences. One is an "old" list and the other is a "new" list. When comparing the nested lists, they can be considered equal if all of the NESTED list items (the MyObject.Ids) are present in both lists in order (you can assume that the nested MyObject.Ids lists are already sorted and that there are no duplicates). The MyObject.Id and MyObject.Name properties are not considering in the equality comparison, but they are still important metadata for MyObject's which should not get lost.

I am not looking for a boolean indicator of equality. Instead I need to create three new lists which capture the differences between the old and new lists (e.g. a list of items which were Added, a list of items which were Removed, and a list of items which were present in both lists).

Below is an example of some code which does exactly what I want! What I would like to know is how to make this shorter/better/simpler (cutting out one of the for loops would be a good start). To make things trickier, please assume that you cannot make any changes to the MyObject class or use any custom Equals/IEqualityComparer etc implementations.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
}

...

// Get the list of existing objects (assume this returns some populated list)

List<MyObject> existingObjects = GetExistingObjects();

// Create a list of updated objects

List<MyObject> updatedObjects = new List<MyObject>()
{
    new MyObject()
    {
        Ids = new List<Guid>() { new Guid("48af3cb9-945a-4ab9-91e4-7ee5765e5304"), new Guid("54b5128a-cf53-436c-9d88-2ef7abd15140") }
    },

    new MyObject()
    {
        Ids = new List<Guid>() { new Guid("0485382f-8f92-4a71-9eba-09831392ceb9"), new Guid("3d8b98df-caee-41ce-b802-2f0c5f9742de") }
    }
};

// Do the comparison and capture the differences

List<MyObject> addedObjects = new List<MyObject>();
List<MyObject> removedObjects = new List<MyObject>();
List<MyObject> sameObjects = new List<MyObject>();

foreach (MyObject obj in updatedObjects)
{
    if (existingObjects.Any(list => list.Ids.SequenceEqual(obj.Ids)))
    {
        sameObjects.Add(obj);
        continue;
    }

    addedObjects.Add(obj);
}

foreach (MyObject obj in existingObjects)
{
    if (!updatedObjects.Any(list => list.Ids.SequenceEqual(obj.Ids)))
    {
        removedObjects.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little shorter (due to elimination of the second loop) and little better (due to elimination of the ineffective search contained in the second loop). Still O(N^2) time complexity due to ineffective search contained in the loop though.

```
var addedObjects = new List<MyObject>();
var removedObjects = new List<MyObject>(existingObjects);
var sameObjects = new List<MyObject>();
foreach (var newObject in updatedObjects)
{
    int index = removedObjects.FindIndex(oldObject => oldObject.Ids.SequenceEqual(newObject.Ids));
    if (index < 0)
        addedObjects.Add(newObject);
    else
    {
        removedObjects.RemoveAt(index);
        sameObjects.Add(newObject);
    }
}
```

**Update:** A shorter, but IMO definitely not better (in fact worse performance wise) version

```
var addedObjects = updatedObjects.Where(newObject => !existingObjects.Any(oldObject => oldObject.Ids.SequenceEqual(newObject.Ids))).ToList();
var removedObjects = existingObjects.Where(oldObject => !updatedObjects.Any(newObject => newObject.Ids.SequenceEqual(oldObject.Ids))).ToList();
var sameObjects = updatedObjects.Where(newObject => !addedObjects.Any(addedObject => addedObject.Ids.SequenceEqual(newObject.Ids))).ToList();
```

If `MyObject` does not define custom equality comparison, i.e. uses default reference equality, the last line could be replaced with shorter and better performing

```
var sameObjects = updatedObjects.Except(addedObjects);
```

Comment: That's cool - thanks! Any idea if the remaining foreach can somehow be removed using some Linq magic or ?

Comment: Another quick question, why is it better to use var in the foreach instead of MyObject given that the type is well known?

Comment: @DaveUK (1) One loop is the best I can think of. Note that there is no magic in LINQ, in fact most of the LINQ methods are loops. Even if the above can be expressed somehow with 3 LINQ statements, I'll never take that way because it will be extremely inefficient. (2) I'm not saying if it's better or not - it's just a personal preference. But let me ask you the same - lambda expressions support **explicitly** defining type of the parameters, why you are not doing that - in your example, why not `.Any((List<MyObject> list) => ...`. The cases are identical, and the benefit - less verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Intersect** and **Except** function in Linq

With Intersect you will get existing object,

and with Except you will get new objects.

Example of Except from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);

foreach (double number in onlyInFirstSet)
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Comment: I'm aware of those two Linq functions, but your example is not the same as my problem. Your example operates on two lists, not two "lists of lists" i.e. nested lists. That seems to be where the complexity arises.

Comment: Now I see you have a nested list. 
Maybe you can use 'SelectMany' to flat 'updatedObjects' and get all Ids in one long list.

Comment: Flattening the list will lose context of which MyObject the Ids belonged to. See in the example that eventually you need to return the actual MyObject that differed, not just the Ids within that MyObject.

Comment: I think the clearest way to see the problem is to actually take my example code above, run it and see what it produces (it will produce the right output) then see if you can use any techniques to shorten/improve the code. That's the challenge :)